# is there a way to compile a JavaScript string, store and use variables from the compiled string?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to build an HTML preprocessor that would help me out with my electron project. I have looked at other preprocessors and none meets my expectations so I decided to create mine. Here is an example of the code format or syntax.

```
{{@import Button from './components/Out'}}

{{@Component {
    name: 'Button',
    useStrict: true,
    props: {
        name: '',
        className: '',
        values: ''
    }
}}}
    {{@include './index', {
        name: props.name
    }}}
    <button class={{props.className}}>{{{name}}}</button>

    {{@if (avatar !== null || avatar !== undefined) }}
        <li class={{`${props.name}`}}>
            this is a test {{avatar}}
        </li>

        {{@each field in values}}
            <span class="d-flex">
                {{field.name}}
                <small>
                     power level: <b>{{field.power}}</b>
                </small>
            </span>
        {{/each}}
    {{/if}}

    <Button name="" text="" value="" href=""/>


{{/Component}}

//---- the problem is below; compiling the code and storing the values of each global variable
<@
    let avatar = 'My avatar is on the run';

    const values = [{name: 'Batman', power: '200kilowatts'}, {name: 'Spiderman', power: '60watts'}];

    const func = () => {
        let name = 'David';
        script = name;
    }
@>
```

I have parsed the entire file or code, and everything works fine but compiling that script.

> **NB:** *I used `Esprima` to extract the script's global variables*.

First, I thought of using the window object to compile the script, that way, I can get each variable's value by calling `window[variableName]` I am using node js so I imported `Jsdom` but unfortunately it didn't work, `window[variableName]` kept returning `undefined`.

Then I thought of `eval`, but that also brought up issues because I can't make use of the variables in `eval`, so I thought of dynamically creating those variables first or saving them in the `global` object, but it certainly won't work, at least as far as I know.

Sorry for the long description.. the summary is, that I need to be able to get each variable's value after the string has been compiled. I have tried finding `js-engines or js-compilers` that can be installed with `npm` but not much luck with that. Also just in case, someone says they found a similar preprocessor, please, I have done my research and there isn't any similar. I placed a lot of functionality to this preprocessor and it's an important component for my electron project... So any help is perfect.... thank you for your time.

Comment: i don't understand why you want to do that to be honest, there is something wrong here, there is no reason at all to build your own, not in a million year, use vuejs or similar frameworks like react, or a templating engine like mustache or handlebars

Comment: @Lk77 I don't really see the problem in wanting to build my own, I mean, React was built because someone wanted it, someone felt that the current tech was not helping matters... do I need some sort of grand reason to want to build mine?? do you have some sort of insight to help me out with this problem? if you do, please help me out or stay out. As I said in my description, I have researched other preprocessor and nothing can help me out with my project.

Comment: @Lk77 I said all that with all due respect, and no offense intended...

Comment: Unless you are also willing to write your own JavaScript runtime engine - your only bet is `eval()`

Comment: @Davy well you can build your own for sure, but it's not an easy task, i just wanted to point out that you choose the harder path. And for your issue if you use node.js try to use global instead of window. But i guess eval is the way to go

Comment: @Lk77 I understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution i come up with :

```
<script>
    let jsCode = `
    var test1 = 'var';
    const test2 = 'const';
    let test3 = 'let';

    console.log(this.globalCtxVar);

    return {
       test1,
       test2,
       test3
    }
`;
    let ctx = {
        globalCtxVar: 'testVar'
    };


    let fn = Function(jsCode);
    ctx = Object.assign(ctx, fn.call(ctx));
    console.log(ctx)
</script>
```

it allow to exec js code using Function and export variables using return, also ctx can be accessed within the code with this

at the end of the execution ctx looks like :

```
{
    "globalCtxVar": "testVar",
    "test1": "var",
    "test2": "const",
    "test3": "let"
}
```

So in the end it's the same as eval but with greater control of input/outputs since it's a function

Comment: Hmmm.... This looks like an interesting fix....  I was actually thinking of using eval but before that, I would have used  js-parsers to find and replace `const or let or var keywords` and their variable names like this  `$.variableName` where `$` is a variable referencing `global`. Something like this:

Comment: And with that I would have access to the eval variables... Thanks your for input, it is really an interesting fix; exporting the variables using return..

Comment: Wow, thank you for this stuff.... I was using Eslint and ended up writing unending programs, then I thought to look at your answer again and the thought of creating my `export keyword` came to mind and wow, it works great.  I used eslint to create a program that converts `export const name = ''; export function email().. etc` to `return {name, email}`. your thought saved me a lot of stress.. thank you

Comment: glad i can help